# iOS - Adding controls on top of AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, video, user-controls, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a subclass of AVPlayerViewController that I want to add my custom controls on it. I successfully added my custom controls on top of the AVPlayerViewController. However, these controls are only responsive for a short time. After a few seconds, clicking any of the button won't trigger the touchUpInside event.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
class LSPlayerViewController : AVPlayerViewController {

private var btnPlay : UIButton!

func addControls() {
    self.showsPlaybackControls = false
    
    //PLAY BUTTON
    let btnPlayRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 19, height: 25)
    btnPlay = UIButton(frame: btnPlayRect)
    btnPlay.center = self.view.center
    btnPlay.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PauseIcon"), for: .normal)
    btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btnPlay.alpha = 0
    btnPlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(btnPlay)
}

func playButtonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender.isPlayIconOn == true {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PauseIcon"), for: .normal)
        self.player?.play()
    } else {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlayIcon"), for: .normal)
        self.player?.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27253734/1971013), which I found in ten seconds, help?

Comment: I checked that as well before posting, however this doesn't resolve my issue. I am adding controls successfully, however the touchUpInside event is not firing after a short amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the following two lines alongside the addSubview function:

```
self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
playerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
playerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```